# Hugo: Adding styling to text blocks without using inline HTML

Tags: html, css, markdown, hugo

So I recently managed to remove all inline HTML from my Hugo blog that was previously used to style the images inserted into my posts. I’ve done this using CSS selectors so that Markdown such as

```
![](Landscape.jpg#align-left)
```

produces the result I want. My question is how do I do something similar for text spans? As an example, I have one blog post where I’m using span blocks to add CSS to set the text color. These effects have disappeared now that I removed the following from my config.toml file. I needed this block to get the inline HTML to render previously.

```
[markup]
   [markup.goldmark]     
      [markup.goldmark.renderer]        
         unsafe = true
```

Is there an analogous idea to what I’m using for images to apply to text?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @CodeMonkey I'm curious if you have any thoughts on this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pure CSS with specific selector codes to format your images. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
img {width:150px;}
</style>
```

would set the defauly width of an image to 150px.